# Errors while compiling java source code for Hangman game

Tags: java, compiler-errors

It's been 3 months since I started learning Java.

I'm pretty much new to Java.

As part of course work I was given class work to develop Java source code for hangman game using `instantiable` class. 
All are using `Filereaders` to read input from user, but instead I'm trying to solve it using `Scanner` class to get it more simple and straight-forward.

But im getting errors as "class interface or enum expected". I tried editing code many times but its of no use. Kindly tell me where i was doing wrong.

The expected output is to let the player know his lives, guesses and other statistics to be displayed everytime he enters a new letter.

Thank you.

This is my code:

**Main class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    int lives = 7;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String name = "", response = "y";

        HangmanApp appobj = new HangmanApp();

        System.out.println("Please Enter your name: ");

        int games_played = 0, games_won = 0, games_lost = 0;

        name = sc.nextLine();

        while ((response.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) || (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))) {
            games_played++;

            if (appobj.runme(randInt()) ) {
                System.out.println("Congrats " + name + " you have won this game!");
                games_won++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry " + name + " you have lost this game!");
                games_lost++;
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Type y or n ");
            response = sc.nextLine();
        }

        // provide statistics after user says no to continue
        System.out.println("Game Statistics-");
        System.out.println("Game played:" + games_played);
        System.out.println("Game won: " + games_won);
        System.out.println("Game lost: " + games_lost);

    }

    public static int randInt() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
        return randomNum;
    }
}
```

Instantiable class - #HangmanApp

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HangmanApp {
    String word_list[] = { "programming", "exhaustive", "violin", "selection",           "repetition", "serendipity",
                            "alabama", "alaska", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", "colorado",
                             "connecticut", "delaware", "florida", "georgia", "hawaii", "idaho",
                              "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana",
                                "maine", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi" };

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in));

    public boolean runme(int index) {

        String correct_word = word_list[index].toString();
        //System.out.println("Word: " + correct_word);
        int corr_wrd_count = correct_word.length();
        int left_lives = 7;

        ArrayList<String> letter_chosen = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> hangman = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        // Insert blank chars
        for(int i =0; i < corr_wrd_count; i++)
        {
            hangman.add("_");
        }

        while (left_lives != 0 ) {
            System.out.print("Guess a letter: ");
            try {
                String letter_entered = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

                if (letter_entered.length() == 1) {
                    if(! isNumeric(letter_entered)) {
                        if (letter_chosen.contains(letter_entered)) {
                            System.out.println("You have already entered this character. Try another.");
                        }
                        else {
                            letter_chosen.add(letter_entered);
                            if (correct_word.contains(letter_entered)) {
                                // Insert the char at all instances of the string
                                for (int i = -1; (i = correct_word.indexOf(letter_entered, i + 1)) != -1; ) {
                                    hangman.set(i, letter_entered);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                // Lost life
                                left_lives--;
                            }
                        }

                        // print status
                        System.out.println("------------------------");
                        System.out.println("Lives: " + left_lives);
                        System.out.println("Word: " + String.join(" ", hangman));
                        System.out.println("Letters chosen so far: " + letter_chosen);

                        // Check if array has any pending -
                        if (! hangman.contains("_")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Buddy this is Hangman not betting... Try entering letter ->");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Please be patient and enter only 1 letter...");
                }
            }
                return false;
            }

        } // end while

    }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
      double d = Double.parseDouble(str);

    {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

}

Comment: When I copy & paste your code to my IDE, it not work, many syntax errors. Let's edit question by yourself. You use many nested conditions, you should use `switch ... case` structure.

Comment: `public static int randInt()`, method is outside the scope of a class. One can not define a method, outside the scope of a class in Java, and still use it. That breaks the Object Oriented Paradigm. Please look to it.. Moreover, where is the `catch block`, if you using a `try block`? I started edited the post, and turns out, even the limits are not matching. Voting to close the question. Please first bring some genuine and proper code, of your effort to the site, for others to have a look. Will highly appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Your isNumeric method is very fishy

```
{
  double d = Double.parseDouble(str);

{
  return false;
}
return true;
```

}

You return true or false? That may be the cause for your error. You have too many curly braces closing. Indent your code properly and check you open and close braces properly.

Also, in your Main class, you have two non static variables, so you can't access them from your static main method.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't compiled it but some of the error that i can see in `Main` Class

Declaring scanner Outside the `public static void main(String[] str){
}` then using it inside will give you error as you are making static reference to non static field

Which is like calling instance methods and fields from within a static method, something that can't be done because instance fields and methods don't exist without an object, and inside of the main method there is not this object. You must instead create an instance of the class, and then call the methods on the instance.

```
public class Main {

int lives = 7;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);//this sc can't be called inside main
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String name = "", response = "y";

    HangmanApp appobj = new HangmanApp();

    System.out.println("Please Enter your name: ");

    int games_played = 0, games_won = 0, games_lost = 0;
    name = sc.nextLine();
```